# C++ Message-Authentication Code Generation & Pointers Issue

Tags: c++, pointers

I am attempting to create a basic MAC-generation program. I will soon add onto this, and therein lies pedagogy. Here's the part of my code that isn't working:

```
int inputsh(char inf)
{
    char input; 
    if (input == 'h')
    {
        cout << "winnow.ch is a program based off of the steganographic method coined by Ron Rivest.\nThough winnow.ch does not run off of standalone chaffing & winnowing, it runs through a multistep procedure.\nThe first step it takes after chaffing & winnowing the individual bits is to record and encrypt each bit\nvia a geosynchronous algorithm, and stores them personally on your computer so that nobody else may access the\ndata without having the encrypted UNIX timestamps on their hard drive.\nNext, the numbers are smacked into one huge number, and from there encrypted with 256-bit AES\nand stored inside a passcode-protected read-only file system." << endl;
        cout << "If you would like to read more about winnow.ch and its procedure, enter 'h'." << endl; 
        cout << "If you would like to encrypt text, enter 'e'." << endl;
        cout << "If you would like to decrypt text, enter 'd'." << endl;
        cout << "Choice: "; 
        cin >> input; 
        inputsh(input); 
    }
    else if (input == 'e')
    {
        char* string binary;
        binary = gVariable('c', 0);
        cout << "NOTICE: To begin working with winnow.ch, you must first convert ASCII to binary." << endl;
        cout << "Because it is rather tedious to implement this for a simple C++ program, you must use a convertor." << endl;
        cout << "http://bit.ly/bq2yy3 -- this is a tool programmed by Roubaix Interactive that can convert for you." << endl;
        cout << "I, Beau Perkins, do not own Roubaix Interactive, nor the program that was linked above." << endl; 
        cout << "Once you have converted your full text to binary, please paste it here: " << endl;
        cin >> binary; 
        cout << "Storing each bit inside an array..." << endl;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=strlen(binary);i++)
        {
            int* bits; 
            char* string binary;
            binary = gVariable('c', 0);
            bits = gVariable('b', strlen(binary)); 
            bits[i] = binary.substr(i, i); 
            cout << "Generating MAC (message authentication code) for bit..." << endl; 
            ofstream outfile ("MAC.txt"); 
            outfile << bits[i] << ":" << rand() % 1000 << endl;
            outfile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I go to terminal, `g++ main.cpp`, and the following errors return:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int gVariable(char, int)’:
main.cpp:20:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘int* (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)length) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
main.cpp:19:8: warning: address of local variable ‘bits’ returned [enabled by default]
main.cpp:24:16: error: expected initializer before ‘binary’
main.cpp:25:3: error: ‘binary’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: In function ‘int inputsh(char)’:
main.cpp:46:16: error: expected initializer before ‘binary’
main.cpp:47:3: error: ‘binary’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:59:17: error: expected initializer before ‘binary’
```

I'm trying to swallow something that's a bit more than I can chew, but, this is all just experience. What's happening?

Here is gVariable:

```
int gVariable(char w, int length)
{
    if (w == 'b')
    {
        int* bits[length];
        return &bits;
    }
    if (w == 'c' && length == 0)
    {   
        char* string binary; 
        binary = ""; 
        return &binary;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1: in "inputsh" method, you are not initializing "input" variable 2: you need to declare "binary" variable, is it char or int ? 3: provide us the definition of "gVariable" method to figure out line number 20

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand `char* string binary;`. Is it a `std::string` involved, or is it two variables with a missing comma?

Comment: @Icarus3 binary is a char string, i edited the post so that it displays gVariables

Comment: @BoPersson What are you asking?

Comment: @cygorx - In C++ we have the types `std::string` and `char*`, but there is no type called `char* string`. On the other hand, `char* string, binary;` (note the comma) would declare two variables. Or maybe you want `char* binary;` or `std::string binary;` or `char binary[some_size];`? You have to decide.

Comment: @cygorx your gVariable method supposed to return "int" but you are returning something else: "return &bits" ? "return &binary" ?

Comment: @BoPersson, I have a C++ reference book and it literally states that there's a difference between the type `char` and `char string`, it states that `char string` is not `char a; a = 'a'`, but it is `char string a; a = "hello, world!";` rather than using `std::string`. I might have been reading this incorrectly though. I was using it so that I could user strlen().

Comment: @Icarus3, gVariable() is a pretty poor method of creating global non-constant variables I thought up, basically whenever you call it, it shall return the variable you called for that you may personally set it, it's set up as a pointer rather than simply the variable.